# Microsoft Flows not starting at all

Tags: microsoft-flow, flow

So I had a look through the material for Flow and it looked pretty cool... however, as with so much in 365, it is just plain not working.

I've created a couple of flows (one using the template that copies a tweet to Yammer when #sharepoint is in the tweet, and one from blank that when an item is created in a list overwrites one of the columns) for testing, but despite repeatedly fulfilling the trigger conditions neither one is starting.

I've got site owner in the SP area I'm using so I doubt it's security related - the Run History shows nothing at all for either, even after 30 minutes or more.

Is there some sort of tenant-level setting I'm missing to make the Flows work? Everything looks fine to me according to MS' instructions.

Comment: You can check the flow history to know how many times it triggered and any errors in flow.

Comment: As I said the flow history is not showing any entries despite the trigger conditions having been met.

Comment: what happened when you run manually

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the flow?  Mostly likely the trigger is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

False alarm it seems - I've got a manual pushbutton one working from my mobile and the one I created based on an SPList item being created kicked in as well.

According to the flow history the latter ran fine yesterday at 15:34 when I created the item... funny how I sat for about an hour refreshing it and nothing was happening or showing in the history.